# VM cannot access webserver outside of internal network! (Ubuntu Desktop 12.0.2)

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 12.0.2 or lets just say 12.x.x
I am running in Virtualbox, with NAT and Host-only, and I am running the latest version of Sentora, VPS Control Panel, And I am trying to accsess my website panel.genisyn.tk that's being hosted on my linux guest, but it's only able to be accsessed over all devices within the iternal network, I cannot accsess it at work, school, or anywhere else!

1. I have port forwarded all required ports, TCP & UDP (About 11 ports)
2. I have set my Sentora DNS servers to my Domain Registerer correctly.
3. I have set my domain registerer DNS correctly.

I feel like it's because I cannot push my IPv4 address to my public address.

Comment: There are two suggestion for you to check.  First try configuring your network for Bridge.  Also consider that some ISP's block port 80.  If you are using port 80 for one of your server try changing it to port 8080 or some other port.

Comment: My ISP actually has a built in control panel for port forwarding port 80 easily, and I have tried bridging already, doesn't work.

Comment: It's unlikely that your ISP actually created the control panel.  I have used control panels from service providers that have features that they don't support.  I've also spoken with ISP representatives for support and found that many times just asking them doesn't give the best or correct answer.   You may save some time by actually performing your own test to verify the port's availability.  You can test port 80 by temporarily turning on the remote management of your routers and running `telnet [router-public-address]:80` from `somewhere else`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to `ping 8.8.8.8` and it was fixed...

I think the real cause was it wasn't connected to Google's DNS